# How to extract a selected word with its surrounding?

Tags: r, string

I must solve a specific problem with R.

I've got a rather big collection of texts, and a dictionary of words of interest.
I need to remove everything from each entry, except for the words from dictionary and their neighborhood of set size. For example, the dictionary contains the word "cat",
we've got a vector like this:

"Yesterday I fed my cat and afterwards took him for a cat-walk in the park, where the cat chased some poor birds".

So assuming i set the distance for 1, I expect to get "my cat and a cat-walk the cat chased".

Also, has anybody got an idea how to do the same thing but instead of set size of neighborhood, we only keep sentences containing the word of interest?

Cheers,
Maciek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tidytext option.

So the value of this solution is that you can more easily supply a vector a vector of terms and retrieve the expected options.
It also fits nicely into a tidyverse workflow if that's what you're using.

The logic is that you are splitting the text into ngrams, that is buckets of n words. So if we set n = 3 then we can look for the middle word to find the two nearest neighbours.

```
text <- "Yesterday I fed my cat and afterwards took him for a cat-walk in the park. Where the cat chased some poor birds. Poor in the sense that we felt sorry for the birds, I'm sure that financially they were doing well"


sample <- tibble(text = text)

library(tidytext)

sample_long <- sample %>% 
        unnest_tokens(bigrams, text, 
                      token = "ngrams", n = 3) %>% 
        separate(bigrams, into = c('first', 'second', 'third'), 
                 sep = ' ')

dictionary <- c('cat')

sample_long %>% 
        filter(second %in% dictionary) %>% 
        unite(col = text, c('first', 'second', 'third'), 
              sep = ' ')

# A tibble: 3 x 1
  text          
  <chr>         
1 my cat and    
2 a cat walk    
3 the cat chased
```

If you want to run for sentences where cat is a term its a little trickier with this approach. The regex might be a lot simpler.
note that I've added sentences to your text and put in a sentence which doesn't refer to a cat.

```
sample_long <- sample %>% 
        unnest_tokens(sentences, text, 
                      token = "sentences") %>% 
        mutate(id = row_number()) 


dictionary <- c('cat')

sample_long <- sample_long %>% 
        unnest_tokens(word, sentences, 
                      token = "ngrams", n = 1) %>% 
        group_by(id) %>%
        filter(word %in% dictionary) %>% 
        distinct() %>% 
        ungroup() %>%
        left_join(sample_long, by = 'id')

> sample_long
# A tibble: 2 x 4
     id word.x word.y sentences                                            
  <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>                                                
1     1 cat    cat    yesterday i fed my cat and afterwards took him for a…
2     2 cat    cat    where the cat chased some poor birds.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution.

```
T2 = gsub(".*?(\\b\\w*\\W*cat\\W*\\w*\\b)", "\\1 ", text)
sub("(.*cat\\W*\\w*).*", "\\1", T2)
[1] "my cat and a cat-walk the cat chased"
```

The `gsub` takes care of everything except that it leaves extra word after the last instance of "cat". The sub cleans up those extra words.